# Criação de um forum, duvida entre quais linguagens usar

Tags: php, html, mongodb

estou criando um fórum de discussão do zero, mas ja tenho boa parte do esqueleto web como: criação de um topico, responder e visualizar topico. Minha duvida é entre usar o php (não manjo nada ainda) ou jquery mais API, e o banco a ser utilizado será o mongodb. O que vocês com mais experiência aconselha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite Mayla, como você já parece ter escolhido usar o MongoDB acho que seria interessante partir para a utilização de Express, NodeJS e AngularJS. Um framework do tipo JavaScript Fullstack.
Entre as vantagens:

- Você trabalha somente com javascript;
- Tem ampla documentação e componentes na internet;
- jQuery é uma ótima biblioteca, mas adorei trabalhar com o AngularJS, o código fica menor e é mais fácil de manter e evoluir, se integra bem com bootstrap, como não sou um designer de mão cheia isso é um diferencial importante pra mim;
- Roda em qualquer plataforma: Windows, Linux ou iOS;

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Complementando a resposta: para mais detalhes acesse http://mean.io/#!/